# Way to utilise 2 tables within a single query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had an assessment on pulling data from a table but i had to use two tables to do a calculation, i figured out a way to do it but it doesn't look good neither it would be good to keep using this way

```
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM metal");
                $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM conversion WHERE type = 'EUR'");
                $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
                $query3 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM conversion WHERE type = 'USD'");
                $data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);

                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $data['metal'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $data['cost'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . ($data['cost'] * $data3['amount']) . "</td>" . "</tr>";
                }
```

This grabs cost on metal type then using another table calculates cost in Euro and USD, I don't want to use 3 querys and fetch them 3 times as it isn't computationaly effective is there a better way to do it

Comment: Post your table structure and I can see what I can do to help you

Answer (score 0):

You'd need at least two, since you're fetching from two essentially unrelated tables

```
SELECT * FROM metal
SELECT * FROM conversion WHERE type IN ('EUR', 'USD')
```

the second query will fetch BOTH records, and then you'll just need some extra code to sort out which record is which.

Comment: could you explain what 'type' and 'In' do please

Comment: uh, `type` is a field in YOUR original query. If you don't know what it is, then how should I? As for `in`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177682.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your overall table structure? In case you have a relation between these two table you could just join it.

Comment: i can't do anything to the table as it's a table provided by the exam board

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get. Don't you know the structure of tables? By `join` I mean SQL clause. You don't have to do anything with tables manually